# Full region name geodata, where to find?

Tags: geolocation

I used MindData's free database for blocks and location data, and then found a free table for full country names (all 249 countries, excluding the 5 disputed ones). My issue is that I'd like to find a table of all the full region names. For example, in the GeoIP location table, the region called MD would be Maryland, but there's no lookup for that particular state. Where can this be found?

Thanks all,
-Steve

Comment: interesting - can you put links to the free databases

Comment: Sure! GeoLite:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

And to import into a db like MySQL:
http://atomboy.isa-geek.com/plone/Members/acoil/programing/how-to-really-import-the-maxmind-geoip-free-country-csv-file-into-mysql

Enjoy,
-Steve

Comment: In case you want a list of country codes (2 and 3 character) and full country names (and other info) hit it up here: http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.html

CSV here: 
http://www.andrewpatton.com/countrylist.csv

Comment: And a little more comprehensive: http://www.floresense.com/resc_center/_Downloads/countrylist.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MaxMind documentation for the GeoIP database includes that exact question in their FAQ: [Where can I get a conversion table of region codes to names?](http://www.maxmind.com/app/faq#fips)

(They provide their own look-up tables, both for the US and Canada and for other countries.)

Comment: Thank you very much! There's something to be said about digging around a site's FAQ!